# Is it possible to set up a private Mercurial repository on Google Code?

Tags: mercurial, repository, private, google-code

I like the fact that Google Code is a free option for Mercurial hosting but, in the test project I set up I couldn't find a way to designate the repository as **private**.

Ideally I would like to work on a project privately until it is ready for the world to see and only then open it up to others.

Is there any way to do that on Google Code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can always use bitbucket.

Comment: Please note that the support for Mercurial repository will be removed in Bitbucket on june 1, 2020

Answer (score 12):

I'm pretty sure the answer is no...the whole point of Google Code is free hosting for open source projects. Open source projects by their nature are not private. If you are planning on releasing the code for free, why so worried about keeping it private? Nobody is going to care if you publish unfinished code...I mean that's 90% of the open source projects online.

Another thought...isn't Mercurial a distributed source code control system? Couldn't you just run the Mercurial locally until you are ready to publish, then at that point push it up to Google Code?

Answer (score 2):

Bitbucket allows one private repository for each free account.

Comment: UPDATE: in the meantime Bitbucket was acquired by Atlassian, and they changed the plans: now every user can have unlimited private repositories, the only thing that depends on the plan is the number of users that can access these private repositories. In the free plan the maximum is 5 users.

Comment: oh wow that is AWESOME! i wish i had found out about this earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to vote/star [issue 1829](http://code.google.com/p/support/issues/detail?id=1829&q=private&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Milestone%20Priority%20Stars%20Owner%20Summary):

[Provide support for proprietary licensed projects with private access.](http://code.google.com/p/support/issues/detail?id=1829&q=private&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Milestone%20Priority%20Stars%20Owner%20Summary)